# How can I convert a string to object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I know this question has been answered many times before. 
But my string is a little different from others. Here's my data:

`let str = "{'name':'joe', 'text':\"that's amazing\", 'registered':True, 'height':193, 'related':{'foo':'bar', 'some':'thing'}}"`

and I am looking for something like: :

`let obj = { name: 'joe',text:"that's amazing", registered:true, height: 193, related:{foo:'bar', some:'thing'}}`

Comment: If at all possible, you should fix the data source to provide well-formatted JSON so that you can just use `JSON.parse()` and call it a day. If that isn't possible, you *may* be able to use `eval()` instead but be aware that that comes with large security risks.

Comment: @DanO Does that *look* like a JSON string to you?

Comment: the contents of the string do not matter; the process of converting a string of JSON to an object literal is the same.

Comment: @DanO The content does matter, because that's not/invalid JSON...

Comment: yep, you're all correct. my mistake

Comment: The second example does not pass an online validator as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `replace()` and `JSON.parse()`:

```js
let str = "{'name':'joe', 'registered':true, 'height':193, 'related':{'foo':'bar', 'some':'thing'}}";
let obj = str.replace(/'/g,'"');
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

**Update:** Since you are having apostrophe in your string, you can try using [JSON5 API](https://github.com/json5/json5) which is compatible with the [JSON API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON):

```js
let str = "{'name':'joe', 'text':\"that's amazing\", 'registered':'True', 'height':193, 'related':{'foo':'bar', 'some':'thing'}}";
let obj = JSON5.parse(str);
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/json5@^2.0.0/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JosephRback, `let str = "{'name':'joe', 'text':"that's amazing", 'registered':True, 'height':193, 'related':{'foo':'bar', 'some':'thing'}}"` is not valid in JS:)

Comment: sorry, corrected, actually the string comes from database, and i want to get only 'text' filed value of string

Answer (score -2):

You can convert a JSON formatted string to object by parsing the string, like so: `let obj = JSON.parse(str);`

Comment: this works when string is in json format and my string is not